# How can I use local rotation on objects created with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have geometry nodes to spawn in objects all over my mesh. Currently they rotate with the mesh, so on a sphere they all point outwards, which I want. But I now want them to be rotated around their 7 axis, so they aren't all lined up. If I use an `Attribute Randomize` node set to `rotation` then it resets all their rotations, and they are all pointing directly upwards.

How can I make them rotate on their local axis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **Point Rotate** node with setting **Point**, Z rotation is what you need:

[image]

If you want to rotate in a random angle use Attribute Randomize in vector mode, but keep X and Y equals 0:

[image]